# ¿Origen de la expresión "ir a tabla"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, vocabulario-técnico

Ayer, hablando de navegación, escuché lo siguiente:

> *—La navegación a vela es otra historia. En cuanto subes al barco, te olvidas de todo lo demás. Con motor no, con motor llevas 200 caballos detrás y hasta que no los pones todos a correr parece que te falta algo, hay gente que se sube y lo primero que hace, arranca y **va a tabla**. Con vela es distinto. Estás pendiente del mar, de si la vela esto o el timón lo otro, no tienes prisa por llegar.*

Cuando la persona dijo "va a tabla", hizo un movimiento como de empujar una palanca con la mano, lo cual suele hacerse en un barco para acelerar.
El significado de la expresión, por tanto, creo que lo entiendo: quiere decir "acelerar al máximo, ir a toda máquina".
Ahora bien, la entrada de **[tabla](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Ysg8s8S)** en el DLE no recoge ninguna locución parecida.

¿De dónde viene esta expresión, pues? ¿Por qué "tabla"? ¿Es una expresión regional, o se usa en otras partes? ¿La entendí mal?

Comment: Nunca había oído eso pero buscando en internet parece que se usa en coches sobre todo y por el contexto de los textos en que lo he visto sí parece que es ir "a toda pastilla" o algo similar. https://www.google.es/search?biw=1045&bih=844&ei=6vRdWpf7K4GgUpeihpgL&q=%22va+a+tabla%22++motor&oq=%22va+a+tabla%22++motor&gs_l=psy-ab.3...137443.137985.0.138562.5.5.0.0.0.0.100.426.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.347...33i22i29i30k1.0.ZVMm60XR18o

Comment: Parece pregunta perfecta para Arturo Pérez Reverte, experto en navegación.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, parece que _tabla_ es una palabra que tiene un significado propio en navegación: _TABLA - Planchuela triangular de plástico o aluminio con uno o dos ollaos estampados, que sirve como refuerzo al puño de driza de la vela Marconi_ ([fuente](http://www.waypointgijon.com/wabpoint_cp_034.htm#tango))

Comment: Is it similar to the usage in motoring in English of putting your foot to the floor in order to accelerate? I am not sure if _tabla_ could mean here the surface on which the boat throttle is fixed.

Comment: It would be control panel I think not board.

Comment: ¿Podrías preguntar a la person que lo dijo si oíste bien?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que la expresión no se limita al ámbito náutico, a tenor del siguiente [ejemplo](http://africaoverland.es/index.php?action=profile;u=122534;area=showposts;start=3960) encontrado en un foro:

> Tras el reconocimiento efectuado vuelvo a cambiar de idea y regreso a mi intencion original de ir con un viejo Peugeot 505 en vez de con el Mercedes de 180 CV. 4MATIC. Porque pienso ir "a tabla", a toda leche, voy a quitar las alfombrillas para que el pedal del acelerador baje mas, [...].

Esto descarta su uso exclusivamente náutico, por lo que la expresión pasa a ser una expresión coloquial como cualquier otra. Otra cuestión diferente es su origen. ¿Por qué "tabla"? Para eso resulta algo esclarecedor el siguiente ejemplo encontrado en el CREA:

> Tanto más condenable me parece aquel deporte [de la caza] cuando se produce de la manera que se suele practicar entre nosotros, esto es, a tabla rasa, sin ninguna limitación, a despecho mismo de la conservación de las especies explotadas.
>
> Francisco Tamayo, "El hombre frente a la naturaleza", 1993 (Venezuela).

Nótese el uso de *[a tabla rasa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ysg8s8S#3ot9gOj)* como sinónimo de "sin ninguna limitación" (el DLE define *hacer tabla rasa de algo* como "prescindir o desentenderse de ello", entiendo que el texto se refiere a los límites del deporte de la caza, a sus normas). Si no se ponen límites a la hora de pisar el acelerador en un coche o barco, acabas yendo a la mayor velocidad posible, "a toda máquina" como comentabas.

De ahí se puede haber simplificado la expresión y quedarse simplemente en "a tabla", como se ve en el primer ejemplo expuesto y en el comentario citado en la pregunta. Esta simplificación como "a tabla" será probablemente regional, yo particularmente no recuerdo haberla oído.

Comment: Ejemplos como esos es lo que encontré yo en su día y puse en un comentario, tiene sentido además con la frase original cuando dice: _«hay gente que se sube y lo primero que hace, arranca y **va a tabla**. Con vela es distinto.(...), no tienes prisa por llegar»_