# ¿Uso de "medir" para indicar que algo te golpea en la cabeza?

Tags: expresiones

De los creadores de "[ir a tabla](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/origen-de-la-expresi%C3%B3n-ir-a-tabla)", nos llega ahora... "**medir**":

> *Cuando entras a un barco, nada más entrar por la puerta, el bao **te mide**.*

Los [baos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4z6Js1g) son unos travesaños en los que se apoya la cubierta del barco. Por tanto, cuando entras al interior del casco del barco, los baos son como vigas en el techo.

En la expresión anterior, *«el bao **te mide**»* quiere decir *«el bao **te golpea en la cabeza**»*.
Entiendo la analogía: si eres bajito/a no te das, y si eres alto/a sí. El bao es el que "mide" ([por las bravas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=63pF2Fd), jeje) si cabes o no... Pero vaya, que no lo había oído nunca. En el DLE, por descontado, no viene ninguna acepción de "[medir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Om9ZDVF)" como "golpear en la cabeza".

¿Habíais oído alguna vez esta expresión, o parecida, en un sentido tan... físico?
¿Es de uso común en otras zonas, o es que este hombre se va inventando las expresiones sobre la marcha?

Comment: Es que no significa golpearte la cabeza. Significa que mide tu altura. La elipsis es: "si mides más que la altura del bao te llevas un golpe en la cabeza".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La he oído muy pocas veces, pero se entiende perfectamente.

Viene de la analogía con el proceso de medirte la altura. Cuando te miden la altura, normalmente se hace sobre una cinta métrica sobre la pared, o cualquier escala graduada desplegada en vertical. Pues bien, para situar correctamente la marca, normalmente se toma un objeto plano, como por ejemplo una carpeta, para colocarlo sobre la cabeza, y se mira dónde coincide con la escala graduada. De ahí se toma el dato de tu altura.

Pues bien, es un dicho que viene a significar que la viga hace las veces de esa carpeta, es decir, que queda rasante con la línea de tu cabeza. Desconozco si en otras zonas fuera de España se lleva este significado más lejos y se aplica también cuando tu cabeza la sobrepasa, pero no hay duda de que la expresión viene de ahí.

Comment: Pues no lo recuerdo, sinceramente, pero desde luego han sido muy, muy pocas veces. La cuestión es que, aunque me suene raro, la entiendo, por lo que explico en la respuesta.